# Combine Two Xcode Projects with common files

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, static-libraries

I have two xcodeprojects named as **Master.xcodeproj** and **Slave.xcodeproj** .I had added static library on Slave.xcodeproj  and added that as a sub project in Master.xcodeproj.  Slave.xcodeproj has a viewcontroller  **SlaveViewController**  and Master.xcodeproj have a viewcontroller **MasterViewController**.

Now, if I want to load SlaveViewController from a button click of a MastViewcontroller.m is that possible?

**UPDATE:**

Ok you can reference the files of Slave project with **#import"SlaveLibraryName/SlaveViewController.h"**. But the problem now I am facing is that I am getting duplicate symbols messages from the library since the Slave had files that were referenced from Master project and those files were added to static library. how to overcome that ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. All the code from each project can be available so you can do this normally by importing the header of SlaveViewController and instantiating it (or by segueing to one in a storyboard). One complication with a static library is that it will not automatically add resources such as images, xibs, or storyboards to your target project.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. so how do i add images .xibs etc that I need from the Slave.xcodeproj?

Comment: ok I got to get it work with the link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/iOSStaticLibraries/Articles/configuration.html

Comment: Great! add that answer and select it.